# Why is numpy much slower than matlab on a digitize example?

Tags: python, performance, matlab, numpy

I am comparing performance of *numpy vs matlab*, in several cases I observed that numpy is significantly slower (indexing, simple operations on arrays such as absolute value, multiplication, sum, etc.). Let's look at the following example, which is somehow striking, involving the function **digitize** (which I plan to use for synchronizing timestamps):

```
import numpy as np
import time
scale=np.arange(1,1e+6+1)
y=np.arange(1,1e+6+1,10)
t1=time.time()
ind=np.digitize(scale,y)
t2=time.time()
print 'Time passed is %2.2f seconds' %(t2-t1)
```

The result is:

> Time passed is 55.91 seconds

Let's now try the same example **Matlab** using the equivalent function **histc**

```
scale=[1:1e+6];
y=[1:10:1e+6];
tic
[N,bin]=histc(scale,y);
t=toc;
display(['Time passed is ',num2str(t), ' seconds'])
```

The result is:

> Time passed is 0.10237 seconds

That's **560 times faster!**

As I'm learning to extend Python with C++, I implemented my own version of digitize (using boost libraries for the extension):

```
import analysis # my C++ module implementing digitize
t1=time.time()
ind2=analysis.digitize(scale,y)
t2=time.time()
print 'Time passed is %2.2f seconds' %(t2-t1)
np.all(ind==ind2) #ok
```

The result is:

> Time passed is 0.02 seconds

There is a bit of cheating as my version of digitize assumes inputs are all monotonic, this might explain why it is even faster than Matlab. However, sorting an array of size 1e+6 takes 0.16 seconds (with numpy.sort), making therefore the performance of my function *worse* (by a factor of approx 1.6) compared to the Matlab function *histc*.

So the questions are:

- Why is numpy.digitize so slow? Is this function not supposed to be written in compiled and optimized code?
- Why is my own version of digitize much faster than numpy.digitize, but still slower than Matlab (I am quite confident I use the fastest algorithm possible, given that I assume inputs are already sorted)?

I am using Fedora 16 and I recently installed ATLAS and LAPACK libraries (but there has been so change in performance). Should I perhaps rebuild numpy? I am not sure if my installation of numpy uses the appropriate libraries to gain maximum speed, perhaps Matlab is using better libraries.

**Update**

Based on the answers so far, I would like to stress that the Matlab function *histc* is **not equivalent** to *numpy.histogram* if someone (like me in this case) does not care about the histogram. I need the second output of hisc, which is a mapping from input values to the index of the provided input bins. Such an output is provided by the numpy functions *digitize* and *searchsorted*. As one of the answers says, *searchsorted* is much faster than *digitize*. However, searchsorted is *still slower than Matlab by a factor 2*:

```
t1=time.time()
ind3=np.searchsorted(y,scale,"right")
t2=time.time()
print 'Time passed is %2.2f seconds' %(t2-t1)

np.all(ind==ind3) #ok
```

The result is

> Time passed is 0.21 seconds

So the questions are now:

1. What is the sense of having *numpy.digitize* if there is an equivalent function *numpy.searchsorted* which is **280 times faster**?
2. Why is the Matlab function *histc* (which also provides the output of *numpy.searchsorted*) **2 times faster** than *numpy.searchsorted*?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your C++ version of digitize? It is a bit hard to say why your version might perform differently to what is in numpy without seeing it....

Comment: I dont see how any of the functions used is related to ATLAS or even LAPACK. Those libraries will not be used here and hence do not effect the results.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First, let's look at why `numpy.digitize` is slow. If your bins are found to be monotonic, then one of these functions is called depending on whether the bins are nondecreasing or nonincreasing (the code for this is found in `numpy/lib/src/_compiled_base.c` in the numpy git repo):

```
static npy_intp
incr_slot_(double x, double *bins, npy_intp lbins)
{
    npy_intp i;

    for ( i = 0; i < lbins; i ++ ) {
        if ( x < bins [i] ) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return lbins;
}

static npy_intp
decr_slot_(double x, double * bins, npy_intp lbins)
{
    npy_intp i;

    for ( i = lbins - 1; i >= 0; i -- ) {
        if (x < bins [i]) {
            return i + 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, it is doing a linear search. Linear search is much, much slower than binary search so there is your answer as to why it is slow. I will open [a ticket](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2656) for this on the numpy tracker.

Second, I think that Matlab is actually slower than your C++ code because [Matlab also assumes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/histc.html) that the bins are monotonically nondecreasing.

Comment: Excellent point, given my low reputation I cannot unfortunately vote this answer up :-)

Comment: I think Matlab is much slower than my C++ code because I am cheating, not only my function assumes non decreasing bins but also non decreasing input values (x in the code above).I believe that if I would generalize my code, e.g. by having a python wrapper which just sorts the inputs, then applies my function, then re-orders according to the initial ordering, **my C++ code would be slower than matlab** .I think it would also be useful to tell digitize (or searchsorted) if the input is already sorted,to speed up even more (gaining a potential factor of 5, using my code as benchmark).

Answer (score 6):

I can't answer why `numpy.digitize()` is so slow -- I could confirm your timings on my machine.

The function `numpy.searchsorted()` does basically the same thing as `numpy.digitize()`, but efficiently.

```
ind = np.searchsorted(y, scale, "right")
```

takes about 0.15 seconds on my machine and gives exactly the same result as your code.

Note that your Matlab code does something different from both of those functions -- it is the equivalent of `numpy.histogram()`.

Comment: Thanks Sven, np.searchsorted does the same thing of numpy.digitize much faster! I get 0.21 seconds in my example. As I wrote to @JoshAdel, numpy.histogram() is not equivalent to histc in Matlab, it is perhaps more similar to hist (except that hist takes the centers of the provided interval as bins and not the edges). The beauty of histc is that is returns not only the histogram (which I do not need at all) but also the mapping from inputs to edges (which I need for synchronization purposes). What is still unsolved is why is searchsorted by a factor 2 slower than matlab (2nd output of histc).

Answer (score 2):

Before the question can get answered, several subquestions need to be addressed:

1. In order to get more reliable results, you should run several
   iterations of the tests and average their results. This would
   somehow eliminate startup effects, which do not have anything to do
   with the algorithm. Also, try to use larger data for the same
   purpose.
2. Use the same algortihms across the frameworks. This has already
       been addressed in other answers here.
3. Make sure, the algorithms are really similar enough. How do they
       utilize system ressources? How is iterated over memory ? If (just an
       example) a Matlab algorithm uses repmat and the numpy would not, the
       comparison is not fair.
4. How does the corresponding framework parallelize? This possibly
       is connected to your individual machine / processor configuration.
       Matlab does parallelize some (but by far not all) builtin functions.
       I dont know about numpy/CPython.
5. Use a memory profiler in order to find out, how both implementations
   behave from that performance point of view.

Afterwards (this is only a guess) we probably will find out, numpy does often behave slower than Matlab. Many questions here at SO come to the same conclusion. One explanation could be, that Matlab has an easier job to optimize array access, because it does not need to take into account a whole collection of general purpose objects (like CPython). The requirements on mathematical arrays are much lower than those on general arrays. numpy on the other hand does utilize CPython, which must serve the full python library - not only numpy. However, according to this [comparison test](http://ilnumerics.net/blog/fast-faster-performance-comparison-c-ilnumerics-fortran-matlab-and-numpy-part-i/) (among many others) Matlab is still pretty slow ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are comparing the same functions in numpy and matlab. The equivalent to `histc` is `np.histogram` as far as I can tell from looking at the documentation. I don't have matlab to do a comparison, but when I do the following on my machine:

```
In [7]: import numpy as np

In [8]: scale=np.arange(1,1e+6+1)

In [9]: y=np.arange(1,1e+6+1,10)

In [10]: %timeit np.histogram(scale,y)
10 loops, best of 3: 135 ms per loop
```

I get a number that is approximately equivalent to what you get for `histc`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I fear that the equivalent of the Matlab histc is NOT np.histogram. histc returns also (as second output) a mapping from values of the input to bins. This is what I need, np.digitize provides this mapping, help(np.digitize):  "Return the indices of the bins to which each value in input array belongs.